# How to get a timestamp (for Time Series analysis) when data is in seconds, using python?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series, timestamp

I have a dataset (see image 1) that I want to analyze for anomalies.

The story of the dataset is the following:
I measured temperature (TPU, CPU), memory (MemUsed) and time (Time) for each inference (an image classification task).
I also made a cumulative sum of the 'Time' column in order to get the time that the whole process of classifying 70000 images will take. This is around 7000 seconds.

The following code is what I get when trying to get a Timestamp (aka '_time'). And in Image 2 you will see how does it look.

```
#Return the index with frequency (RangeIndex to DateTimeIndex)
df1_MAX['_time']=pd.to_datetime(df1_MAX['TimeTotal'])#string to DatetimeIndex
df1_MAX=df1_MAX.set_index('_time')
df1_MAX
```

As I am working with data in seconds, how can I get a proper Timestamp? what format do I need to use?

Thank you

Image 1

[image]

Image 2

[image]

------------------EDIT--------------
Using timedelta64

[image]

---------------EDIT------------

I changed 'TimeTotal' to ms. And also put 'timedelta64[]' in ms.

```
df1_MAX['_time']= pd.to_datetime("2020-07-06 10:53:00")+df1_MAX['TimeTotal'].astype('timedelta64[ms]')
df1_MAX=df1_MAX.set_index('_time')
df1_MAX
```

[image]

Comment: You mean you measured time lapse?

Comment: I measured the duration of each inference (Time). Yes, the lapse.

Comment: what do you mean by "*proper Timestamp*" and "*what format*"? do you mean *datatype*? - note that this will depend on what you want to do with the data, i.e. what problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can make it a time delta then

```
df['TIME']= df['Time'].astype('timedelta64[s]')
```

If you wanted to create a datetime stamp, say you began at `2021-07-06 10:53:02`. Just add the timedelta to the start datettime.

**Data**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Time": [121.83,101.22],"score": [1,2],"Label": ["trimaran", "trimaran"]})
```

**Solution**

```
 df['DateTime']= pd.to_datetime("2021-07-06 10:53:02")+df['Time'].astype('timedelta64[s]')
```

Outcome

```
   Time      score     Label            DateTime
0  121.83      1  trimaran  2021-07-06 10:55:03
1  101.22      2  trimaran  2021-07-06 10:54:43
```

Comment: I do not understand. Can you check the EDIT, please?

Comment: You can only change a time interval to a timedelta. Did you want to make it a time stamp? On what date?

Comment: 'Time' is in ms. 'TimeTotal' is in seconds. This last one is a cumulative sum of 'Time'. Because 'Time' varies. Sometimes is high and other is low.

Comment: Yes, I just made some changes in the 'TimeTotal' scale and 'timedelta'.